# Grails YAML list of maps

Tags: grails, configuration, yaml

In my Grails 3 application.yml, I'm defining a list of maps as follows:

```
tvoxx:
    cfpApis:
        -
            url: http://cfp.devoxx.be/api/conferences
            youtubeChannelId: UCCBVCTuk6uJrN3iFV_3vurg
        -
            url: http://cfp.devoxx.fr/api/conferences
        -
            url: http://cfp.devoxx.ma/api/conferences
            youtubeChannelId: UC6vfGtsJr5RoBQBcHg24XQw
        -
            url: http://cfp.devoxx.co.uk/api/conferences
        -
            url: http://cfp.devoxx.pl/api/conferences
```

But when I try to load this config in my service using the following code, apiConfig is null:

```
def apiConfig = grailsApplication.config.getProperty("tvoxx.cfpApis")
```

I don't get any error when the application starts and my YAML code parses correctly on http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ so I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to confirm what we discussed on Slack.

Using `grailsApplication.config.getProperty("tvoxx.cfpApis")`, Grails will try to find value of type `String` and because your value is a Map null will be returned.

You have to explicitly tell what type you expect, using:
`grailsApplication.config.getProperty("tvoxx.cfpApis", Map)`

Other way is to use `getAt()` method, where object is returned, so you can use
`grailsApplication.config.tvoxx.cfpApis` to get the value.

First one may be better for `.java` and `@CompileStatic` but for standard `.groovy` class latter has easier syntax. Just watch out for keys which does not exist, because it will return empty `ConfigObject` instead of `null`, and for example `?.toString()` method will result in `'ConfigObject@123123` instead of `null`